# Syslog Ng detecting f5 logs as a directory due to hostname written attached as "local/" or "slot1/"

Tags: syslog-ng

We have a system in place where we have a bunch of f5 devices sending logs to syslog-ng. We have syslog-ng configured to go to:

```
/path/to/directory/$HOST.
```

This is causing a problem because since /local is in the hostname field it tries to send it to:

```
/path/to/directory/local/ or /path/to/directory/slot1/.
```

Since we do not want to create directories the error is:

```
Directory does not exist.
```

I have tried a syslog-ng rewrite rule to subsitute the /local and /slot1 in the hostnames to local- and slot- but it does not seem to be working.

Here is the rewrite rule:

```
    rewrite r_f5{
        subst("slot1/", "slot1-", value("HOST"), flags("global"), flags("ignore-case"));
        subst("slot1/", "slot1-", value("MESSAGE"), flags("global"), flags("ignore-case"));     
        subst("local/", "local-", value("HOST"), flags("global"), flags("ignore-case"));
        subst("local/", "local-", value("MESSAGE"), flags("global"), flags("ignore-case"));
};
```

Please note that the Message rules were due to the Host rules not working.

Here is the logging rule:

```
log { source(s_network_f5); rewrite(r_f5); destination(d_network_f5);};
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with the rewrite rule?

Comment: What version of syslog-ng are you using?

Comment: I am using the free version of syslog-ng 3.8.1

Comment: Hmmm will call a host .. /.. /etc/passwd

Comment: Fortunately, `../` is not allowed :) -> Spurious path, logfile not created

Comment: Hi have you tried using the host-override() option of the network source?

Comment: No but seems promising I will give it a shot. Thanks!